# How to unhide filtered messages in Chrome developer Tools on a MAC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am in the developer view in Chrome <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Under the console tab, it shows this message

> 7 items hidden by filters

But the issue is I have no filters set. I tried right clicking and selecting 'Filter' but the unhide all is greyed out. And tried reseting the developer console.But it didnt work, how do i fix this ?

Comment: If you truly don't have any filter applied, post a screenshot showing that. I suspect you do.

Comment: To the right of the filter box is the logging level. Most of the time its set to info i think. Click on it and set it to verbose and it should show you everything.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in chrome, when adding filters via the rightclick context menu:

`Filter > Hide Messages from ...`

The only thing that worked for me, was to reset the entire debugger settings

`Settings (F1 on Windows) > DevTools > Restore defaults and reload`

Comment: Clicking on the bottom button "Restore defaults and reload" was actually the solution for me thanks

Comment: You need to select verbose which will show "All Levels"

Comment: This fixed the  debugger command not working too not sure why

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I could not change the log level, the button was grey and disabled for me. This saved me

Comment: "Settings (F1 on Windows) > DevTools > Restore defaults and reload" fixed it for me. FYI I'm on a mac and clicking the main "gear" icon in devtools brings up devtools settings in the preferences panel. The "Restore defaults and reload" button is the very last item (bottom, right) on that view.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the correct answer. It's a shame they added a function to filter messages, but no way of undoing the filter.

Answer (score 155):

You need to click on the circled X in the filter area, or focus the filter area and delete the text typed there.

[image]

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me after accidentally clicking 'Hide messages from...'

Comment: Best answer IMO. Thanks.

Comment: This was the best answer as per the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Well that was dumb. The action was ***hide*** messages, so I couldn't find an "unhide" or "show" because all this while, it was just filtering it out.

Comment: This is the new correct answer please tag it as that !

Comment: Pictures are worth a 1000 words

Comment: for me, nothing was there but i decide to write something and click on X . and it's work

Comment: Wow, one step.. solved it all!.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 56):

Right click on console area, Filter -> Unhide All, in filter option you will see all filters.
[image]
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTJRe.png)

Comment: I forgot I had hided some message from a script... Thanks for point that out!

Comment: Am I the only one who doesnt see that option

Comment: This no longer seems to be an option (at least in Chrome 78). Answer by @Phrogz cleared the filters for me.

Answer (score 26):

You must close the "console sidebar" to enable the log level filter. DevTools has this sidebar closed by default, which is why "Restore to defaults" also works.

[image: How to close the console sidebar]

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution I was looking for. IMO that's a bad user experience. Would be good if you could select multiple levels from the sidebar as well to filter out specific log levels.

Comment: This did the trick! Nothing else helped for me either... Utterly broken button... Sigh!

Comment: Thanks for this. It is utterly unintuitive. Adding some keyword flair here: chrome console "default levels" greyed out trying to disable verbose logs.

Answer (score 9):

Onl following worked for me.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> inside dev window

type 'settings' in search field and open it

click 'restore defaults and reload' in lower right corner

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue and resolved now following the below steps.

- Right click in the browser and select *Inspect*
- Go to *Console*
- Click on the button shown in the screenshot and select *Default* from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is to select either "Info" or "Verbase" option next to filter field to see the console log.

Answer (score 6):

For those for whom none of the mentioned solutions helped out, you can try following:

While Console is opened press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then a little window will pop up where you can run commands.

One that concerns us is:

> **Console** Show messages from all contexts

[image: Console Show messages from all contexts]

Answer (score 5):

Check for a small input box above the console, You may have set a entered some text once as a filter and forgot to clear it.

Comment: This is golden. It's stupid that the text isn't cleared when the dev panel is closed.

Answer (score 4):

in your chrome console,

click **default levels** -> enable/check all values

refresh your page ..

now it wont filter anything if you checked all...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue the other day. Go to the console in your dev tools and right click on an error message. Hover over 'filter' option, then select unhide all.

console > right click error message > filter > unhide all

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem but selecting "info" or "verbose" didn´t unhide errors, what was hidding them for me was, "Hide network" inside console settings, was checked, so i just unchecked and no "items hidden by filters" showing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What really worked for me was to click on the settings button, right top of the console window, and unselect

"Hide Network" and "Selected context only"

My settings became like that:

[image]