# console log does not show info logs anymore

Tags: electron, chromium, developer-tools

I don't know what happened exactly, but I am not getting console.log  statements shown in my log anymore. It says "xx hidden", but does not mention why does statements are hidden. See screenshot. Any ideas?

This is an electron application, however I am not sure if it's related to electron or if I accidentally pressed some standard chrome shortcut for hiding those items.

[image: hidden entries in console.log]

Or look at this screen. So strange- all items invisible:

[image: hidden entries in console.log]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unhide filtered messages in Chrome developer Tools on a MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622318/how-to-unhide-filtered-messages-in-chrome-developer-tools-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally created a filter via right click.
Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46110318/457059

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this issue can be solved by pressing F1 while in the console. At the bottom right, press the 'restore to defaults' button.